# Extract data from JSON field with Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi

I'm using Power BI desktop to connect to a MySQL database.
One of the fields contains data with the following structure:

```
a:1:{s:3:"IVA";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:11:"tax_namekey";s:3:"IVA";s:8:"tax_rate";s:7:"0.23000";s:10:"tax_amount";d:25.07000000000000028421709430404007434844970703125;}}
```

I need to transform the data in a way that allows the extraction of the value of the tax amount. That is, I need to transform this column to: **25.07**.

How can I do this? I tried splitting the column by semicolon, but since not all the columns have the same number of semicolons it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Query Editor has a Parse / JSON format (on the Transform and Add Columns ribbons), but it doesn't recognize that string as JSON.

Comment: The above example doesn't look like valid JSON; not sure if that's because it's just an excerpt or if it just currently isn't. 
(http://jsonlint.com/) 

Valid JSON should be readable / extractable via the JSON format that @MikeHoney described.

Comment: The "JSON" in the example is actually a [serialised](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) PHP value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use this function

Works only for your task - parse number 25.07 from source string

```
(src) => Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({";d:",";"})(src){1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value in the column is not actual JSON file .There is option in power bi itself to split json column but it should be valid json.To check whether is a json file or not try using the link

> https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
>   After that go to edit query right click on the json column and transform-> JSON .

It will transform your json file into columns.

Comment: How will the use of an external service (that can only be used by copy and paste into an HTML form) be better than the existing answer (handling everything in code) that was accepted two years ago?

Comment: In Mysql We can check whether it's a valid json or not .I have given that external source for knowing how the  valid json should  look like just as a example .